# Search within a Google map area outline (neighbourhood)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, wordpress, google-maps-api-3

this community has been really helpful so far!

Does anyone know if there is a possibility of getting the region outline from Google Maps and getting an array of elements within that area? For example, if I type "Brooklyn", I would like to get an array of the properties advertised in my website. I can't find documentation on the API docs...

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in mysql.

You need to store that data in some graph database like neo4j. Mysql is not meant to store such points / graph data. You can only store tabular data in mysql.